# Mesclar dois documentos Word

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-word

Estou com um problema e gostaria de uma força, eu tenho um projeto porém não tenho nenhum código para incluir a minha pergunta.

O cliente está solicitando um botão que junte 2 ou mais arquivos .docx  e transforme em 1 só ou envie para 1 só  o conteúdo.

Queria fazer isso sem API, pelo meu conhecimento básico sei que da pra fazer no word Inserindo o objeto >> e o conteúdo no word propriamente aberto, e como pelo word é possivel acredito que seria necessário utilizar a referência Interopt.Word...
Alguem ja passou pelo mesmo problema e resolveu?

Observação: dei uma pesquisada no site e só havia a duvida do documento **.txt**, tentei efetuar o mesmo processo mas infelizmente não soluciona, o arquivo **.docx** fica danificado.

Comment: Você quer fazer isso sem usar `Interop.Word`?

Comment: Só um detalhe, o [pt.so] [não é um fórum](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum)

Comment: Usando o interop.word, acho quem sem ele não é possivel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal seria que você realizasse esse procedimento utilizando uma biblioteca, pois arquivos .docx não são simples arquivos de texto, eles estão num formato chamado [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) que é um formato de arquivo baseado no XML.

Sobre as bibliotecas eu fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei duas que você poderia se interessar em utilizar:

- Utilizando o [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document.aspx), que requer que o Microsoft Word esteja instalado. Essa biblioteca cria uma instância do Word para realizar as operações em cima de um documento, então é necessário que o mesmo esteja instalado na máquina do cliente.
- Ou utilizado a biblioteca [DocX](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX), que consegue realizar a montagem de documentos do Word sem a necessidade de ter o programa instalado na máquina do cliente.

Se você optar por utilizar o `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` dê uma olhada [nessa resposta de uma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929799/1324082) no Stack Overflow em inglês, ela possui um exemplo de como realizar o *merge* de documentos do Word.

Para evitar que essa resposta se invalide no futuro vou colocar aqui a mesma solução que pode ser encontrada no link acima:

A classe:

```
using System;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Configuration;

namespace KeithRull.Utilities.OfficeInterop
{
  public class MsWord
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the default Word Document Template file. I suggest that you point this to the location
    /// of your Ms Office Normal.dot file which is usually located in your Ms Office Templates folder.
    /// If it does not exist, what you could do is create an empty word document and save it as Normal.dot.
    /// </summary>
    private static string defaultWordDocumentTemplate = @"Normal.dot";

    /// <summary>
    /// A function that merges Microsoft Word Documents that uses the default template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filesToMerge">An array of files that we want to merge</param>
    /// <param name="outputFilename">The filename of the merged document</param>
    /// <param name="insertPageBreaks">Set to true if you want to have page breaks inserted after each document</param>
    public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks)
    {
        Merge(filesToMerge, outputFilename, insertPageBreaks, defaultWordDocumentTemplate);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A function that merges Microsoft Word Documents that uses a template specified by the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filesToMerge">An array of files that we want to merge</param>
    /// <param name="outputFilename">The filename of the merged document</param>
    /// <param name="insertPageBreaks">Set to true if you want to have page breaks inserted after each document</param>
    /// <param name="documentTemplate">The word document you want to use to serve as the template</param>
    public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks, string documentTemplate)
    {
        object defaultTemplate = documentTemplate;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        object pageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
        object outputFile = outputFilename;

        // Create  a new Word application
        Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application( );

        try
        {
            // Create a new file based on our template
            Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(
                                          ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

            // Make a Word selection object.
            Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

            //Count the number of documents to insert;
            int documentCount = filesToMerge.Length;

            //A counter that signals that we shoudn't insert a page break at the end of document.
            int breakStop = 0;

            // Loop thru each of the Word documents
            foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
            {
                breakStop++;
                // Insert the files to our template
                selection.InsertFile(
                                            file
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

                //Do we want page breaks added after each documents?
                if (insertPageBreaks && breakStop != documentCount)
                {
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
                }
            }

            // Save the document to it's output file.
            wordDocument.SaveAs(
                            ref outputFile
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing);

            // Clean up!
            wordDocument = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //I didn't include a default error handler so i'm just throwing the error
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Finally, Close our Word application
            wordApplication.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

E a chamada:

```
using System;
using KeithRull.Utilities.OfficeInterop;

namespace WordDocMerge2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string document1 = @"D:\Visual Studio Projects\31.docx";
            string document2 = @"D:\Visual Studio Projects\33.docx";
            string document3 = @"D:\Visual Studio Projects\32.docx";

            string[] documentsToMerge = { document1, document2, document3 };

            string outputFileName = String.Format("D:\\Visual Studio Projects\\{0}.docx", Guid.NewGuid( ));

            MsWord.Merge(documentsToMerge, outputFileName, true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //messageLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom cara, funcionou perfeitamente, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Que bom que consegui te ajudar. :)

Comment: Beleza, testado e marcado como resposta. Unico problema é a formatação que ficou tudo desregulado, mas ai ja não faz mais parte da pergunta. Grato pela resposta.

Comment: @GabrielBorghi o KeithRull.Utilities.OfficeInterop é a namespace onde a primeira classe foi definida, você pode mudar e colocar a que está sendo utilizada no seu projeto.